# LESS Ruby Compiler Error

Tags: css, less

Out of nowhere, all of my stylesheets started throwing errors during compilation.

```
lessc static/css/styles.less
/gems/less-2.2.1/lib/less/js/lib/less/parser.js:385:31: .rounded_corners is undefined (Less::Error)
```

None of my mixins seem to be available in the main less file. The mixins.less file is imported at the very top of my stylesheet and is only imported once.

```
@import "mixins.less";
@import "reset.less";
@import "clearfix.less";
@import etc..
```

I've also checked each file for a Byte Order Mark, inspired by [Variable Name Error "is undefined" even though "variables.less" imported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9146708/less-css-variable-name-error-is-undefined-even-though-variables-less-impo), and even went back 4 weeks in this project's git history (where I'm 100% sure compilation ran successfully). I have had no luck thus far.

Oddly enough, compilation runs successfully using [SimpLESS](http://wearekiss.com/simpless) and [Less Compiler for Mac](http://incident57.com/less/).

I've narrowed this down to an importing issue because if I attempt to use a mixin at the top of the stylesheet and error is thrown with that mixin's name.

Anyone familiar with this situation?

I'm using version 2.2.1 of the [Less Ruby Gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/less/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to be in the directory that contains the file you are trying to compile. Instead of running the command as:

```
lessc static/css/styles.less
```

try:

```
cd static/css
lessc styles.less
```