# in grunt.js, during uglify "jquery" and "blockui" i get error "Unexpected Character `?`"

Tags: jquery, blockui, uglifyjs, gruntjs

if i "min" the jquery and blockui files (with uglify.js) in grunt i get
the following error

```
Unexcpected Character "?"
```

How i can fix this ? Is this a known problem?

Thx in advance.

Comment: I'm getting the same problem, but not necessarily with Jquery.  I've seen this with other minification libraries when accidentally trying to re-minify code that was already minified, but that's not my issue this time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah ha!  I figured it out based on [some previous experience](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9146708/less-css-variable-name-error-is-undefined-even-though-variables-less-impo/10639157#10639157).

One or more of my files was encoded in UTF-8 with a BOM, try re-saving your file in ANSI or UTF-8 without BOM.

If your editor doesn't have an obvious way to change the encoding, try using [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/).

Comment: Thank you so much. Was pulling hairs trying to figure this out!