# Defining variables across files in Less CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm trying to create a CSS theme with multiple color schemes using Bootstrap CSS. Each color scheme is built as a modified version of the `boostrap.less` file: `bootstrap-red.less`, `bootstrap-green.less`, and so on.

What each Bootstrap version does is import all the default Bootstrap files, then the appropriate color palette, then the theme's core structure. For example, `bootstrap-red.less`:

```
@import "reset.less";
@import "variables.less";
@import "mixins.less";

/* and so on... until */

// Custom code
@import "elements.less";
@import "_mytheme-color-scheme-red.less";
@import "_mytheme-core.less";
```

In `_mytheme-color-scheme-red.less`, I define variables such as:

```
@bannerBackground: #59a449;
```

However, when compiling `bootstrap-red.less` I get:

```
NameError: variable @bannerBackground is undefined in /.../css/less/_mytheme-core.less
```

Why does this happen? I would have thought it would work, since variables in the `variables.less` files are defined in the same way, and they can be used in subsequent files.

I've looked at similar questions and tried different things, but to no avail:

- `@import`ing `"_mytheme-color-scheme-red.less"` in the file `_mytheme-core.less` - unfeasible; also, Bootstrap doesn't do that and yet it still works.
- encoding the files in UTF-8 without BOM - didn't work, same result.

It seems to me the file `_mytheme-color-scheme-red.less` is not being processed at all. It's as if the Less compiler was just skipping it and going straight for `_mytheme-core.less` How can I fix this?

Comment: This sounds like my experience with LESS, at least when using SimpLESS to compile it.  One of many reasons I've switched preprocessors.  Is passing the variables via mixins not an option?

Comment: Which compilation method are you using ? Have you tried importing your variables right after `variables.less` ?

Comment: @Sherbrow I tried it right now, and the result was the same. I really don't get it, it *always* skips my variables file no matter what.

Comment: @cimmanon I'm compiling with the Node.JS version of LESS, I had no idea there were other compilers around. What are you using now that works? Also, I understand mixins, but I can't think of a way to use them to achieve what I want, could you give me an example?

Comment: I switched to Sass after SimpLESS released its new version a few months ago and made my files not compile properly. WinLESS had even more problems compiling, so it was either install Ruby for Sass (which was my first choice anyway) or install Node.JS.  Ruby was the lesser of two evils in the eyes of my server's admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. The problem was the encoding after all: the LESS compiler was skipping all wrongly encoded files. Apparently Sublime Text doesn't properly save to UTF-8 without BOM even if you tell it to; my files were all in either ANSI or UTF-8 *with* BOM. I had to resort to Notepad++ in order to convert them to plain UTF-8. I feel stupid now.

Source: [Variable Name Error "is undefined" even though "variables.less" imported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9146708/less-css-variable-name-error-is-undefined-even-though-variables-less-impo)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error with LessCss 2.x when compiling Bootstrap 2, downgrading to LessCss 1.7.5 resolved it for me.